# AWS S3 query string parameter causes method not allowed error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A GET request to this URL returns the file as expected...

```
curl -v 'http://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/lineitems/58ecfff764a6036d96deaa69/bootstrap.min.js'
```

However when I add the specific query string parameter 'select' then I get a 405 method not allowed error.

```
curl -v 'http://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/lineitems/58ecfff764a6036d96deaa69/bootstrap.min.js?select='

< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< x-amz-request-id: 7F3339518976EB66
< x-amz-id-2: 8YmXqeME+Y5bLRdlMhDKQyrznjNJr/gw7ortpLjXqFDlPfYR1Ckqz+2Gr2/35/SWKaNviMLZLEk=
< Allow: POST
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 10:50:33 GMT
< Server: AmazonS3
```

Other query string parameter names do not cause this problem. It only appears to be affecting files in this folder and has only started happening recently (in the last week).

I can't see anything unusual in the properties for the files in this folder and everything gets uploaded to the bucket by the same code.

I'm at a loss to explain why this is happening.

Comment: Try curl -X POST "<URL>"

Comment: Bizarrely that also returns a 405 despite the Allow: POST in the GET response. There's no Accept header in the response though.

Comment: This is the error response from S3. I can't find any documentation for 'ResourceType' -
<Error>
<Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
<Message>
The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
</Message>
<Method>GET</Method>
<ResourceType>SELECT</ResourceType>
<RequestId>5154A10A5A493C4C</RequestId>
<HostId>
PAXPQ9pJYKoIv/tr1cO932iC83yfjvV2HLPC6VRrd6h0Colf7JAixm43T9MXwaTSRKVgQrNooKs=
</HostId>
</Error>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a different parameter name. `select` now has a meaning to S3, so it is no longer quietly discarded.

**Update**: The sudden appearance of the `?select` subresource appears to have been when AWS began deploying a new feature, [S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/), which allows JSON and CSV objects to actually be queried for a subset of their content, using SQL expressions.  The feature was announced later the same month.

The original answer follows.

---

For reasons that aren't readily explainable, `select=` in the query string causes S3 to interpret your request as... something different.  Exactly what it is, is not clear.

```
<ResourceType>SELECT</ResourceType>
```

Interestingly, if you try a POST, you get an error message saying that `POST` is not allowed, either, but the `Allow: POST` is then no longer in the response headers.

The bucket logs show the request operation as `REST.GET.SELECT`, which doesn't seem to be documented, where a normal `GET` request is logged as `REST.GET.OBJECT`.

So you're triggering some unexpected behavior, and you'll need to use something different.

The fact that it previously worked tends to rule out my initial theory, that you were somehow prompting S3 to assume you wanted to make a deprecated SOAP request (which requires `POST`), but if it's really true that this was working all along, then I'm inclined instead to think instead that you may have inadvertently stumbled on a feature that has not yet been released.

Unofficially, S3 silently ignores most unexpected query string parameters.  Signature V2 also ignores them completely (and actually requires them *not* to be signed, if I remember my test results of that algorithm correctly).

Officially, it seems you should be using a query string parameter beginning with `x-` if you definitely don't want the service to interpret it.  This will also write the parameter to the logs, which might prove to be a useful side effect in the future for debugging purposes.

> You can include custom information to be stored in the access log record for a request by adding a custom query-string parameter to the URL for the request. **Amazon S3 will ignore query-string parameters that begin with `x-`**, but will include those parameters in the access log record for the request, as part of the Request-URI field of the log record. *(emphasis added)*
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html

Comment: Very odd. I'm not keen on undocumented, unknowable features. Unfortunately it's not possible to use something different. It's user-defined and has been in the wild for some time. Fortunately it's behind a CDN so it will be straightforward to point the CDN to something which strips off the query string and redirects to S3.

Comment: @JohnnyD take a look at the static web site hosting feature of S3.  Enabling this capability on a bucket creates a second hostname (the website endpoint) with some different behaviors from those of the REST endpoint, and this endpoint does not seem to notice the `?select=` in the query string.  Enabling the feature on an existing bucket won't break anything.  You should be able to point your CDN to that alternate endpoint.  For some reason, I didn't think to check that, before.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @JohnnyD I didn't want to speculate in depth at the time, but I strongly suspected that the `SELECT` operation was a new S3 feature that would be rolled out at AWS re:Invent.  That happened today.  It's now possible to scan objects in S3 with CSV or JSON content, using SQL expressions,
and extract only specific content... without downloading the complete object.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/

Comment: That could be very useful in future applications. In the end using a static website caused other problems so I wrote a simple proxy that strips off the query string. It sits between S3 and the CDN so it's not heavily loaded.